# How to find where an equation equals zero

Tags: r

Say I have a function and I find the second derivative like so:

```
xyr <- D(expression(14252/(1+exp((-1/274.5315)*(x-893)))), 'x')

D2 <- D(xyr, 'x')
```

it gives me back as, typeof 'language':

```
-(14252 * (exp((-1/274.5315) * (x - 893)) * (-1/274.5315) * (-1/274.5315))/(1 + 
    exp((-1/274.5315) * (x - 893)))^2 - 14252 * (exp((-1/274.5315) * 
    (x - 893)) * (-1/274.5315)) * (2 * (exp((-1/274.5315) * (x - 
    893)) * (-1/274.5315) * (1 + exp((-1/274.5315) * (x - 893)))))/((1 + 
    exp((-1/274.5315) * (x - 893)))^2)^2)
```

how do I find where this is equal to 0?

Comment: Put that R expression in a function, graph it to get a better idea regarding its behavior and use `uniroot` to "solve for 0". I'm not sure why one would want a second derivative = 0. Usually one is looking for maxima and minima and that would only require testing the first derivative.

Comment: This might be useful if you have any data that will be fit: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11744012/finding-the-maximum-gradient-of-a-growth-curve

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A little bit clumsy to use a graph/solver for this, since your initial function as the form:

```
f(x) = c / ( 1 + exp(ax+b) )
```

You derive twice and solve for `f''(x) = 0` :

```
f''(x) = c * a^2 * exp(ax+b) * (1+exp(ax+b)) * [-1 + exp(ax+b)] / ((1+exp(ax+b))^3)
```

Which is equivalent that the numerator equals `0` - since `a`, `c`, `exp()` and `1+exp()` are always positive the only term which can be equal to zero is:

```
exp(ax+b) - 1 = 0
```

So:

```
x = -b/a
```

Here `a =-1/274.5315`, `b=a*(-893)`. So `x=893`.

Just maths ;)

++:

- from applied mathematician point of view, it's always better to have closed form/semi-closed form solution than using solver or optimization. You gain in speed and in accuracy.
- from pur mathematician point of view, it's more elegant!

Comment: Maybe you skipped a few steps? The numerator in the equation you posted is "c". I'm guessing you solved for an asymptote. Since the numerator was so high the function crossed the x axis at a point quite close to your asymptotic solution.

Comment: Yes and...? Alright I supposed `c` is different from 0 since it's completely trivial. I could have taken a functional with a form `1/(1 + exp(a*(x-b)))` leading to the same result.

Comment: The same result in the sense that they both have the same asymptote, anyway.

Comment: Just to rectify they do not have the same asymptot ;) One is `c` in `+Inf ` the second form is `1`. Non zero multiplicative factor can just be omitted for  finding roots.

Comment: Maybe my basic math needs help. I was assuming that the denominator being the same and then setting equal to zero created equal asymptotes, but maybe I'm getting confused because the numerator in one of the expressions is approaching infinity at the same x value?

Comment: The denominator of the second derivatives can't be equal to zero anyway, it's a sum of 2 strictly positive quantities. Asymptot is the form of the function when x goes to the limit of the definition domain. Here the definition domain is `]-Inf, +Inf[`. So if you're looking to asymptot you make x tending to `-Inf` and `+Inf` to see how `f` will behave.
Back to initial problem, solving second derivatives for zero has nothing to do with asymptots!

Comment: I finally see your argument (and my error). I never did think that solving 2nd derivative of zero had anything to do with asymptotes.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `uniroot` after having created a function from your derivative expression:

```
f = function(x) eval(D2)
uniroot(f,c(0,1000))  # The second argument is the interval over which you want to search roots.

#Result:
#$root
#[1] 893

#$f.root
#[1] -2.203307e-13

#$iter
#[1] 7

#$init.it
#[1] NA

#$estim.prec
#[1] 6.103516e-05
```